# PHP Upload-show images securely

Tags: web-application, php, attacks, file-upload, image

I've read various posts about how letting users to upload files can create vulnerabilities to your website such as a user injecting php code in an image.

So i've created a small test project where you can upload (outside of web root) and see uploaded images keeping it as simple as i could having in mind security but i'm not an expert and it would be really helpful if you could answer some of my questions and tell me if something could be done better.

---

### Bellow is my test project (working)

---

> 1)Do you spot anything wrong regarding permissions?

**Structure**

```
/
     public_html (root) 755
          .htaccess 444
          index.php 644
          images.php 644
          javascript 755
               show_images.js 644
               upload.js 644
          php_scripts 755
               fetch_images.php 600
               upload_images.php 600
               logo.png 644
     secure_images
          .htaccess 444
          201811051007191220027687.jpg 644
          20181105100719574368017.jpeg 644
     secure_php_scripts 500
          fetch_images.php 600
          upload_images.php 600
```

**public_html/.htaccess**

```
#Deny access to .htaccess files
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

#Enable the DirectoryIndex Protection, preventing directory index listings and defaulting
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php /index.php

#Trackback Spam protection
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(opera|mozilla|firefox|msie|safari).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.+/trackback/?\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F,NS,L]
```

---

***Upload images related files***

---

**public_html/index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Image upload security test</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Image upload security test">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" multiple>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
    <a href="images.php">See images</a>
    <script src="js/upload.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

**public_html/javascript/upload.js**

```
$("#upload_form").submit(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:"../php_scripts/upload_images.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType:"JSON",
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data.outcome) { console.log("Images succesfully uploaded"); }
                else { console.log(data.msg); }
            }
        });
    });
```

**public_html/php_scripts/upload_images.php**

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/../secure_php_scripts/upload_images.php");
```

> 2)Are the checks that i do in upload_images.php to check that the files
>   that are being uploaded are images of the allowed format sufficient? Could
>   i do something better?

**secure_php_scripts/upload_images.php**

```
<?php
$uploaded_images[0]["path"] = null;
try
{
    $isValid = validateArray($_FILES['filesToUpload']);
    if($isValid[0])
    {
        $data['outcome'] = true;
        $data['msg'] = "Images uploaded successfully";
        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['filesToUpload']['tmp_name']); $i++)
        {
            $new_name = date('YmdHis',time()).mt_rand() . "." . pathinfo($_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $path_to_be_uploaded_to = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/../secure_images/" . $new_name;
            if(!chmod($_FILES['filesToUpload']['tmp_name'][$i], 0644) ||
               !move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filesToUpload']['tmp_name'][$i], $path_to_be_uploaded_to)
            )
            {
                $data['outcome'] = false;
                $data['msg'] = "There was an error uploading your file";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                $uploaded_images[$i]["path"] = $path_to_be_uploaded_to;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $data['outcome'] = false;
        $data['msg'] = $isValid[1];
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    //If there is an exception delete all uploaded images
    if($uploaded_images[0]["path"] != null)
    {
        foreach($uploaded_images as $item)
        {
            if( file_exists($item["path"]) ) { unlink($item["path"]); }
        }
    }
    // Also delete all uploaded files from tmp folder (Files user uploads first go there)
    foreach($_FILES['filesToUpload']['tmp_name'] as $item)
    {
        if( file_exists($item) ) { unlink($item); }
    }
    $data['outcome'] = false;
    $data['msg'] = "There was an error please try again later";
    echo json_encode($data);
}

// Create a new blank image using imagecreatetruecolor()
// Copy our image to the new image using imagecopyresampled()
// And also add a logo in the process
function add_watermark($path_to_img, $ext)
{
    try {
        if($ext == 'png') { $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_img); }
        else { $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_img); }
        $stamp = imagecreatefrompng('logo.png');
        // Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
        $marge_right = 10;
        $marge_bottom = 10;
        $sx = imagesx($stamp);
        $sy = imagesy($stamp);

        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path_to_img);
        $dest_imagex = 900;//width of new image
        $dest_imagey = 900;//height of new image
        $dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);//create new image
        imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dest_imagex, $dest_imagey, $width,$height);//#im to $dest_image
        //Now $dest_image is an image of 800x800
        // Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo width to calculate positioning of the stamp.
        imagecopy($dest_image, $stamp, $dest_imagex - $sx - $marge_right, $dest_imagey - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, $sx, $sy);
        $filename = $path_to_img;
        if($ext == 'png') { if(!imagepng($dest_image, $filename)) { return false;} }
        else { if(!imagejpeg($dest_image, $filename)) { return false;} }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// Checks
// if the element provided is a 2D array with the expected elements (multiple pictures per upload)
// if there is an error
// if file extentions are the allowed ones
// is each file size is bellow 1GB
// if the file number is less than 16
// if file exists and if it was uploaded via HTTP POST
function validateArray($array)
{
    try{
        if( $array && is_array($array) )
        {
            if( !is_array($array['name'])) { return [false, "Wrong array format"]; }
            else { $pic_number = count($array['name']); }

            if($pic_number > 15) { return [false, "Maximum image number allowed is 15"]; }

            if( !is_array($array['type']) || count($array['type']) != $pic_number ||
                !is_array($array['tmp_name']) || count($array['tmp_name']) != $pic_number ||
                !is_array($array['error']) || count($array['error']) != $pic_number ||
                !is_array($array['size']) || count($array['size']) != $pic_number
            ) { return [false, "Wrong array format"]; }

            $allowedExts = array('png', 'jpeg', 'jpg');
            $allowedExts2 = array('image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg');
            $fileinfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
            for($i=0; $i<count($array['name']); $i++)
            {
                if( is_array($array['name'][$i]) || is_array($array['tmp_name'][$i]) ||
                    is_array($array['error'][$i]) || is_array($array['size'][$i])
                ) { return [false, "Wrong array format"]; }
                $ext = pathinfo($array['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                if( !in_array($ext, $allowedExts) ) { return [false, "Only PNG JPEG JPG images are allowed"]; }
                if(!file_exists($array['tmp_name'][$i]) || !is_uploaded_file($array['tmp_name'][$i])) { return [false, "File doesn't exists, try again"]; }
                if(!is_uploaded_file($array['tmp_name'][$i])) { return [false, "File has to be uploaded using our form"]; }
                if(!exif_imagetype($array['tmp_name'][$i])) { return [false, "Only images allowed"]; }
                if(filesize($array['tmp_name'][$i]) < 12) { return [false, "All images has to be more than 11 bytes"]; }
                if (!in_array(finfo_file($fileinfo, $array['tmp_name'][$i]), $allowedExts2)) { return [false, "Only PNG JPEG JPG images are allowed"]; }
                if($array['error'][$i] !== 0) { return [false, "File error"]; }
                if($array['size'][$i] > 1000000) { return [false, "Maximum image size allowed is 1GB"]; }
                if(!add_watermark($array['tmp_name'][$i], $ext)) { return [false, "There was an error uploading your file"]; }
            }
        }
        else { return [false, "Element provided is not a valid array"];}
        return [true, "Chill dude images are ok"];
    } catch (Exception $e)
    {
        return [false, "There was an error please try again later"];
    }
}
```

---

***Show images related files***

---

**public_html/images.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Image upload security test</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Image upload security test">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
      section{display:block;text-align:center;}
      content{display:inline-block;margin:10px;height:400px;width:400px;}
      content img{max-height:100%;max-width:100%;min-height:100%;min-width:100%;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
    </section>
    <script src="js/show_images.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**public_html/javascript/show_images.js**

```
window.onload = function() {
  $.ajax({
            url:"../php_scripts/fetch_images.php",
            method:"POST",
            dataType:"JSON",
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data.outcome) {
                    if(data.images)
                    {
                        if(data.images.length > 0)
                        {
                            let text = [];
                            for( let i=0; i< data.images.length; i++)
                            {
                             text[i] = "<content><img src='data:"+ data.extention[i] +";base64," + data.images[i] + "'></content>";
                            }
                            $("section").append(text);
                        }
                    }
                    else {console.log("no images found"); }
                }
                else { console.log("An error occured please try again later"); }
            }
        });
};
```

**public_html/php_scripts/fetch_images.php**

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/../secure_php_scripts/fetch_images.php");
```

> 3)Fetching multiple images using
>   `base64_encode(file_get_contents($images[$i]))` seems a bit slow and
>   also the string that is being put inside img src is huge...can this be
>   a problem (for example images don't appear in xiaomis MIUI browser)?
>   Is there a better alternative?
>
> 4)Let's say that a malicious image bypasses my checks during uploading. When i fetch an images using the following php code get the response
>   in js using ajax and then append it to the dom to be shown to the user
>   using `<img src='data:"+ data.extention[i] +";base64," +
>   data.images[i] + "'>` is it possible to be harmful in any way?

**secure_php_scripts/fetch_images.php**

```
<?php
try
{
    $data["outcome"] = true;
    $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/../secure_images/";
    $images = glob($directory . "*.{[jJ][pP][gG],[pP][nN][gG],[jJ][pP][eE][gG]}", GLOB_BRACE);
    $fileinfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++)
    {
        $extention = finfo_file($fileinfo, $images[$i]);
        header('Content-Type: ' . $extention);
        $data["extention"][$i] = $extention;
        $data["images"][$i] = base64_encode(file_get_contents($images[$i]));
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
} catch(Exception $e)
{
    $data["outcome"] = false;
    $data["images"][0] = [];
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

> 5)Is storing images outside of root trying to prevent access of
>   malicious users too much of a hassle? Is it better maybe
>   (security-speed-browser compatibility wise) to just store them inside
>   root and make use of .htaccess to prevent someone from doing harm?
>   Would an .htaccess like the following be sufficient for that purpose?

**secure_images/.htaccess**

```
#Deny access to .htaccess files
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

#Enable the DirectoryIndex Protection, preventing directory index listings and defaulting
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php /index.php

#Securing directories: Remove the ability to execute scripts
AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI
```